# Adding Akka Library to Intellij Project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka

I'm trying to go through the Akka chapter in the Manning Book "Scala In Action" http://www.manning.com/raychaudhuri/.

Chapter 12 has an Akka project, but no matter what I do I can't get the akka packages to resolve.  I'd like to add the library directly to the project and avoid using SBT, as my team doesn't want to use it, so I'm trying to stay close to our dev environment.

Steps I've taken thus far:
1.  Create Scala project pointing to the Manning.com source code
2.  Added the akka library to the project using the project settings tab[image]

If anyone has experience with this, I'd appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all about location...

had to dig down in the distribution to AKKA_HOME/lib/akka/[image]/akka-2.2.3/lib/akka

Comment: If you are using SBT to build your project, there's a plugin for intellij. You can add the plugin conf in your projects plugins.sbt file, for example (mine looks like this at the moment for one of my projects): resolvers += "sbt-idea-repo" at "http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/". Then you restart SBT, update, and type in gen-idea, which generates an IntelliJ project for you. Voila, all your dependencies configured for you.

Comment: This is generally good advice if you're just experimenting and want something done quickly, but I do not like magic solutions like this and i think it's bad to promote them to the general public. If I can't explain something at an interview, I do not want it done to my project. "Voila" solutions should be used by seasoned senior scala/akka practitioners.